# apt update in WSL fails: Failed to fetch ... no such file or directory

Tags: apt, 20.04, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I already updated WSL itself (as Administrator)

```
> wsl --set-version ubuntu-20.04 2
> wsl --update
```

Which worked but still did not solve my problem inside the WSL Ubuntu 20.04.

```
$ sudo apt update
Reading package lists... Error!
E: Failed to fetch store:/var/lib/apt/lists/partial/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_focal_main_binary-amd64_Packages.xz  rename failed, No such file or directory (/var/lib/apt/lists/partial/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_focal_main_binary-amd64_Packages -> /var/lib/apt/lists/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_focal_main_binary-amd64_Packages).
E: Failed to fetch store:/var/lib/apt/lists/partial/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_focal_main_i18n_Translation-en.xz  rename failed, No such file or directory (/var/lib/apt/lists/partial/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_focal_main_i18n_Translation-en -> /var/lib/apt/lists/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_focal_main_i18n_Translation-en).
E: Failed to fetch store:/var/lib/apt/lists/partial/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_focal_main_cnf_Commands-amd64.xz  rename failed, No such file or directory (/var/lib/apt/lists/partial/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_focal_main_cnf_Commands-amd64 -> /var/lib/apt/lists/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_focal_main_cnf_Commands-amd64).
E: Failed to fetch store:/var/lib/apt/lists/partial/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_focal_restricted_binary-amd64_Packages.xz  rename failed, No such file or directory (/var/lib/apt/lists/partial/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_focal_restricted_binary-amd64_Packages -> /var/lib/apt/lists/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_focal_restricted_binary-amd64_Packages).
E: Failed to fetch store:/var/lib/apt/lists/partial/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_focal_restricted_i18n_Translation-en.xz  rename failed, No such file or directory (/var/lib/apt/lists/partial/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_focal_restricted_i18n_Translation-en -> /var/lib/apt/lists/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_focal_restricted_i18n_Translation-en).
E: Failed to fetch store:/var/lib/apt/lists/partial/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_focal_restricted_cnf_Commands-amd64.xz  rename failed, No such file or directory (/var/lib/apt/lists/partial/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_focal_restricted_cnf_Commands-amd64 -> /var/lib/apt/lists/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_focal_restricted_cnf_Commands-amd64).
E: Failed to fetch store:/var/lib/apt/lists/partial/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_focal_universe_binary-amd64_Packages.xz  rename failed, No such file or directory (/var/lib/apt/lists/partial/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_focal_universe_binary-amd64_Packages -> /var/lib/apt/lists/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_focal_universe_binary-amd64_Packages).
E: Failed to fetch store:/var/lib/apt/lists/partial/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_focal_universe_i18n_Translation-en.xz  rename failed, No such file or directory (/var/lib/apt/lists/partial/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_focal_universe_i18n_Translation-en -> /var/lib/apt/lists/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_focal_universe_i18n_Translation-en).
E: Failed to fetch store:/var/lib/apt/lists/partial/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_focal_universe_cnf_Commands-amd64.xz  rename failed, No such file or directory (/var/lib/apt/lists/partial/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_focal_universe_cnf_Commands-amd64 -> /var/lib/apt/lists/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_focal_universe_cnf_Commands-amd64).
...
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
E: Problem renaming the file /var/cache/apt/srcpkgcache.bin.OL2UsH to /var/cache/apt/srcpkgcache.bin - rename (22: Invalid argument)
E: Problem renaming the file /var/cache/apt/pkgcache.bin.EdYnXG to /var/cache/apt/pkgcache.bin - rename (22: Invalid argument)
W: You may want to run apt-get update to correct these problems
E: The package cache file is corrupted
```

`sudo rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*` and `sudo apt clean` did not help, too. Here are my sources, all from `/etc/apt/sources.list`.

```
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal main restricted
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates main restricted
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal universe
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates universe
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-backports main restricted universe multiverse
# deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu focal partner
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-security multiverse
```

I don't know if this is WSL related or Ubuntu related, but I guess the first as I never had such problems on native Ubuntu.

I use WSL mostly as SSH and Git client.

Anybody knows whats wrong here?

Comment: Try `sudo apt clean` and then `sudo apt update` again.  If that doesn't work, please edit your question with the output of `cat /etc/apt/sources.list`.  Please also post the contents of any other `.list` files in `/etc/apt` or subdirectories

Comment: Do you use Acronis software: https://forum.acronis.com/forum/acronis-true-image-2017-forum/acronisdriveexe-causes-issues-windows-10-subsystem-linux-bash  ?

Comment: YES!!!! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution if you use **Acrons True Image**. Thanks to @jannes-bottis

Press Strg-Shift-Esc

Go to Processes tab, order by name and look for Acronis Drive process. **KILL IT.**

After that, update works.

@Acronis please fix!

https://forum.acronis.com/forum/acronis-true-image-2017-forum/acronisdriveexe-causes-issues-windows-10-subsystem-linux-bash